# How do you obtain the coordinates of a crossing of two perpendicular lines?

Tags: geometry, 2d

Lines (xA, yA), (xB, yB) and (xC, yC), (xD, yD) are perpendicular. I have coordinates of points (xA, yA), (xB, yB) and (xC, yC). How could I get the coordinates of point (xD, yD)?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the right forum for a geometry question. But I would minimize the distance of a parametrized point on the line `AB` from `C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a computer program to perform the computation, then I would like to suggest a simple code written in Python.

Point D can be easily computed just by projecting point C onto the line passing through point A and B (so you need to compute this line):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skspatial.objects import Line, Point

point_a = Point([2, 3])
point_b = Point([7, 8])

line_ab = Line.from_points(point_a, point_b)

point_c = Point([-1, 4])
point_d = line_ab.project_point(point_c)

# Plots
_, ax = plt.subplots()
ax. set_aspect('equal')
point_a.plot_2d(ax, c='k', s=100)
point_b.plot_2d(ax, c='r', s=100)
point_c.plot_2d(ax, c='b', s=100)
point_d.plot_2d(ax, c='g', s=100)
line_ab.plot_2d(ax, t_1=-2, t_2=3, c='k')
grid = ax.grid()
```

Point C is the blue one and Point D is the green one in the plot below.

[image]

Comment: I have also added a plot.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you. In my case I was looking to implement it on R and I managed to find a package thanks to your example. For those who are interested, here is how to do it on R:
library(LearnGeom)
Line <- CreateLinePoints(c(xA, yA]), c(xB, yB))
P <- ProjectPoint(c(xC, yC), Line)